# Extjs: How can I disable text selection while dragging and keep auto-scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Extjs 7.0 and when I drag my panel I see that the text is highlighted (selected), how can I prevent that **while keeping** the auto-scroll work when reaching the parent edges.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up applying css class 'unselectable' to my labels **only**:

```
   .unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[image]